# subscribe to notifications for changes in any of the tenant SharePoint sites using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to use Microsoft Graph in order to create subscriptions (and therefore - notifications) for changes in documents libraries across all SharePoint sites of certain tenant?

I need to be notified when a change is made to a SharePoint site of a tenant (e.g. a file was uploaded to the site document library).

Up until now, I was able to create subscription for changes in the default TeamSite by creating subscription with `resource: drive/root`.

But that's not enough, if I create another TeamSite then I can't find a way to receive notifications for its changes as well.

The same is true for communication sites - I can't find a way to get notifications for changes in them.

Currently, my AAD App is asking only for `Sites.Manage.All` permission, but if asking for more permissions can help then it's not a problem.

Is doing what I want possible? Or notifications are only supported for the default SharePoint TeamSite?

If receiving changes in push by subscribing to notifications isn't possible, then I guess I'll have to poll for changes by using delta links.. that should work for any SharePoint site, right?

Comment: Have you tried `resource: sites/{id of "another TeamSite"}/drive/root`?

Comment: @AllenWu creating a subscription this way is possible, but since there's no endpoint in Microsoft Graph for retrieving all sites in certain tenant then this isn't so helpful. Maybe I can go through all users and for each user ask for his SharePoint sites?

Comment: Currently I think you have to collect the TeamSites. If you are the ShrePoint admin, you can see the sites on SharePoint admin center.

Comment: OK, and is there a way I can get the sites through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the graph today. If you'd like to advocate for such a feature, please post it on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com). The alternative would be to subscribe to each drive individually.

Comment: OK, and is there a way I can get the sites through API?

Comment: Not in a straightforward way today. You can either try to use the search API or enumerate groups (if you only care about groups). Upvote this one for that. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38263330-sharepoint-graph-api-add-list-all-sites-access-fo